# How to plot normal distribution curve for uni variate data using python

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, normal-distribution

How to plot normal distribution curve for univariate data using python. in the below data 493,494,495..... values are just index values. I saw how to plot normal distribution using random values with a mean of 0. Need to know how to plot the curve with univariate data.

Sample dataset is given below:

```
{'RPM': {493: 7.2,
  494: 7.2,
  495: 7.2,
  496: 7.2,
  567: 8.4,
  568: 8.4,
  569: 8.4,
  570: 8.4,
  767: 18.0,
  768: 18.0,
  781: 23.4,
  782: 23.4,
  783: 23.4,
  784: 23.4,
  785: 23.4,
  806: 23.4,
  807: 23.4,
  808: 23.4,
  809: 23.4,
  810: 23.4,
  811: 23.4,
  812: 23.4,
  951: 23.4,
  952: 23.4,
  953: 23.4,
  954: 11.4,
  955: 11.4,
  957: 11.4,
  981: 19.2,
  982: 23.4,
  983: 23.4,
  984: 23.4,
  1062: 23.4,
  1063: 23.4,
  1064: 23.4,
  1065: 23.4,
  1066: 23.4,
  1068: 23.4,
  1069: 23.4,
  1070: 23.4,
  1071: 23.4,
  1072: 23.4,
  1073: 23.4,
  1074: 23.4,
  1075: 23.4,
  1076: 23.4,
  1077: 23.4,
  1079: 23.4,
  1119: 23.4,
  1120: 23.4,
  1121: 23.4,
  1122: 23.4,
  1123: 23.4,
  1125: 23.4,
  1126: 23.4,
  1127: 23.4,
  1128: 23.4,
  1129: 23.4,
  1130: 23.4,
  1132: 23.4,
  1133: 23.4,
  1134: 23.4,
  1135: 23.4,
  1136: 23.4,
  1137: 23.4,
  1159: 23.4,
  1162: 23.4,
  1164: 23.4,
  1165: 23.4,
  1166: 23.4,
  1167: 23.4,
  1168: 23.4,
  1169: 23.4,
  1171: 23.4,
  1172: 23.4,
  1173: 23.4,
  1174: 23.4
```

}}

Comment: how do draw normal distribution curve for above data?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.Series(data['RPM'].keys()) #or df = pd.Series(data['RPM'].values())
kde = df.plot.kde()
plt.show()
```